# Jquery remove table row not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, row

Basically is to click button to generate table row, then click minus button to remove row.

I have tried it with a few ways below, non of it work.
-.bind
-.live
-normal way

It seems like it is not working due to the table is generated dynamically.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {    

  var html = '';
  var rows= 5;
  var cols= 4;

  $('#btnGenTable').bind("click", function() {

   for (var r = 1; r <= rows; r++) 
   {
    html += '<tr>';

    for (var c = 1; c <= cols; c++) 
    {
     cellText= "row " + r + " col " + c;
     html += '<td>aa</td>';
    }

    html+= '<td><img class="delete" src="minus.jpg" /></td>';

    html += '</tr>';
   };


   $('.inner').html('').append(html);

  });


$('table tbody tr td img.delete').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

 });

</script>

<br />


<table id="tblsize" class="inner" border="1" width="80%">
</table>


<input type=button value="Generate Table" name="btnGenTable" id="btnGenTable" class=text100>
```

Comment: works fine for me. Make sure you put " around your attribute http://jsbin.com/iqini3/edit

Comment: pls add an alert box inside ur function and check whether the alert box is coming.

Comment: $('table tbody tr td img.delete').click not working when run as dynamic table, if run as static pre-exist table, it will work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a row when the image is clicked insert the following code in your $(document).ready block.

```
$('img.delete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but I had the same problem. The live() method is deprecated now since jQuery version 1.7 and will be removed in version 1.9. You could use this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need is:

```
  $('.delete').live('click', function(){
          $(this).closest('tr').remove();   
      });
```

in your document ready handler.

here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5bWcT/

Comment: jsfiddle.net is such a great tool